# Google iframe map is not appearing.

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I am going to the google iframe page but the map is not appearing ?
Here is the link http://maps.google.com/maps/empw?url=http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=44.600261,-123.07595&spn=0.008892,0.026071&t=m&z=16&vpsrc=6&output=embed&hl=en&gl=us

Comment: can you share the location, which you want to add through google map?

Answer (score 0):

People have had problems with the new Google Maps and iFrames.  You need to use the new maps engine: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/

There's a good tutorial here, that also mentions how you might go about it the old way but the maps engine is much preferred these days: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/applications/quick-tip-embedding-new-google-maps/